# Access Route Parameter from Blazor Navmenu

Tags: blazor

I have a dropdown in the NavMenu, whose selected value is passed in as a route parameter to all the sub-pages.  On navigating to a new page, the selected value in the dropdown gets wiped because the NavMenu gets reinitialized.  Question is whether there's any way to get this value fed back "up" into the NavMenu on a page load, so that the selected value in the dropdown is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and easiest way to do that is to store the selected value in the local storage, and whenever the NavMenu component is re-rendered, to read the stored value from the local storage, and apply it back to the dropdown

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something along these lines.  I'll probably go with that approach.